# Where Can I save values (properties) in a SharePoint Add-in

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, office-365

In a SharePoint webpart, we have option to save some values into webpart properties

Now for a SharePoint app (SharePoint add-ins), I want user to enter the value say list name and save it somewhere, so that I can use it later

What is the suggested way of implementing something like this?

Comment: You can store the values in custom created list like CustomPropertiesList.

Answer (score 1):

You have these options:

1. create corresponding fields in the tool pane of your add-in part and save your value there (drawback: potential usability issues as the value can be configured in two places)
2. save the data in a hidden SharePoint list in the host web (drawback: values stay there when the add-in part is being removed; permission issues)
3. save the data via a custom service you provide outside SharePoint (possibly lots of work)

The UI of the tool pane cannot be customized. Fields cannot be hidden using ootb means. (Dirty hacks are possible, though.)

We discussed this topic with Microsoft's support and this is basically it.

(Hopefully the SharePoint Framework will give us more options soon. At least it allows us to create visually appealing tool panes.)